# How to nest a field collection?

Tags: 8, entities

How to nest Field Collections in Drupal 8?

I have *Field Collection* installed and working fine. What I want to achieve is that for example, I'll have a box on the front end which may contain 6 tabs of content, or two boxes each containing 3 tabs.

First part is working: I have a 'tabs' Field Collection with which I can 'add another item' (tab).

For the second option I need a 'box' Field Collection that contains nothing but the 'tabs' Field Collection.

Comment: IMO sounds like a problem better suited for Paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks - Kevin, I'll look at that as well, had seen a few posts about theming nested Field Collections though, so assumed it was possible, couldn't find anything on how to actually do it though...

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it @iain-g, The D8 release only made it as far as alpha and it's basically been abandoned (no updates for more than 18 months now). The project page even states _Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use paragraphs instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects._

Comment: OK - Thanks both of you, I'll go and check out Paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module in Drupal 8 seems to NOT be a good idea anymore. It currently only has an [alfa1 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection/releases/8.x-1.0-alpha1) from April 2016). Instead you may want to try to use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) instead, as suggested also on the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) project page, i.e.:

> [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.